# Create multidimensional array from keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to create dynamicaly multidimensional array? I have stored in database "path" for each field=>value like that:

```
field_name : [slideshow][slide][0][title]
field_value : my title

field_name : [slideshow][slide][0][desc]
field_value : my desc

field_name : [slideshow][slide][1][title]
field value : my other title

field_name : [slideshow][slide][1][desc]
field value : my other desc

field_name : [slideshow][settings][duration]
field value : 300
```

and now I'm trying to figure out how to make it an array again. Obviously there can be lots of fields and complexity so I wanted to avoid some recursions if possible, cause I'm not sure how it will impact performance.

I was playing around with variable variables and trying something like:

```
$array_name = 'arr';
${$array_name}[slideshow][slide][1][title] = $field->field_value;
print_r($arr);
```

but this works only if its literally that, and nothing like this works:

```
${$array_name}.$field->field_name = $field->field_value;
```

I basically need to store every field as individual row (e.g. for searches in those fields), values can be diffrent types (even serialized arrays), and contain html.

Any advice appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to split up your field_name string and loop over the parts backward to build up the array. Some recursion is used to merge the arrays, though any performance impact should be negligible.

---

#### Example:

```
// Set up sample data.
$field = new stdClass();
$field->field_name = '[slideshow][slide][0][title]';
$field->field_value = 'my title';
$fields[] = $field;

$field = new stdClass();
$field->field_name = '[slideshow][slide][0][desc]';
$field->field_value = 'my desc';
$fields[] = $field;

$field = new stdClass();
$field->field_name = '[slideshow][slide][1][title]';
$field->field_value = 'my other title';
$fields[] = $field;

$field = new stdClass();
$field->field_name = '[slideshow][slide][1][desc]';
$field->field_value = 'my other desc';
$fields[] = $field;

$field = new stdClass();
$field->field_name = '[slideshow][settings][duration]';
$field->field_value = '300';
$fields[] = $field;
// End sample data.

// array_merge_recursive() doesn't do what we want with numeric keys, so use this
function merge($base, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($base[$key]) && is_array($base[$key]) && is_array($value)) {
            $base[$key] = merge($base[$key], $value);
        } else {
            $base[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $base;
}

$result = [];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $parts  = array_reverse(explode('][', trim($field->field_name, '[]')));
    $value = $field->field_value;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $value = [$part => $value];
    }
    $result = merge($result, $value);
}
print_r($result);
```

---

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [slideshow] => Array
        (
            [slide] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => my title
                            [desc] => my desc
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => my other title
                            [desc] => my other desc
                        )

                )

            [settings] => Array
                (
                    [duration] => 300
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I was trying something similar but couldnt find a way - merge was the answer! - i knew i should build an array backwards. This should work. Gonna try it in a few. Thank you! Anyway do you think that it will be ok for the performance if I do something like that, let say for 200 fields - or should I find a diffrent way (with storing data and its structure)?

Comment: I will test it then. That's true with those jumps. I will create some sample data and see how it will work. If its gonna slow down, I will think about different approach, but it's hard to see something else after so many hours working on current one.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp).

```
     $cars = array
      (
      array("Volvo",22,18),
      array("BMW",15,13),
      array("Saab",5,2),
      array("Land Rover",17,15)
      );

<?php
echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[1][0].": In stock: ".$cars[1][1].", sold: ".$cars[1][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[2][0].": In stock: ".$cars[2][1].", sold: ".$cars[2][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[3][0].": In stock: ".$cars[3][1].", sold: ".$cars[3][2].".<br>";
?>

<?php
for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
  echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
    echo "<li>".$cars[$row][$col]."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LucasZamboulis Oh sorry, didn't really think about that. I fixed it, no need to down vote.